# Need to save opened excel file using subprocess.Popen(excel file, shell=True)

Tags: python, xls

After opening my excel file using "subprocess.Popen(excel file, shell=True)" I am updating the file and terminating it using subprocess.Popen('TASKKILL /T /IM EXCEL.exe', shell=True). While using TASKKILL it is asking me to save the excel or not. "('TASKKILL /F /IM EXCEL.exe', shell=True)" wont work for me as it is giving me recovery option when i am trying to open next file.

Comment: What are you _actually_ hoping to accomplish? Not opening the file in Excel is probably the easiest way forward if you can think of a way.

Comment: @tripleee The open i am talking about is , I want to open EXCEL file externally using python code for that i have used subprocess.Popen and for closing the opened excel file i am using TASK kill. But in middle of open and close i want to save the opened excel file.

Comment: I don't think you can control Excel from Python at all, though it has its own scripting language for those with a strong stomach.

Comment: I am happy to say that i am able to control XLS from python and i am able to update the sheet and expand the columns, I just need to save it before closing it